# how to get Here maps license key validity

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

Is there any api to get Here maps license key validity? Or is there any other way to find out expiry? Plz advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no expiry to license key as long as you are in that particular plan. License Key might be renewed due to some circumstances in which Here notifies its users. Otherwise your license key remains the same for that plan.

Edit based on below comment: There is no public api to get the expiry date for your plan. You have to note it in a configuration file or a database yourself if you need to use it for coding purposes.

Comment: Ours is "SDK Commercial Business Mapping" plan. In web ui I can see the creation and expiry date. Is there any way that I can access these dates via API?